# Actionscript3/PHP : Swf not loading in my site

Tags: php, actionscript, flash

I don't know why, but SWF isn't opening at [my site](http://www.ourvision.co.cc).
You can see that the swf isn't loading. If you try to open the image in a new page, it works. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load a SWF file using an `<img>` tag that's why it's not loading. To embed your SWF file you must replace your `<img>` tag for something like:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="movie_name" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="header.swf"/>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="header.swf" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="header.swf"/>
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Watch out for the width and height of the tag. They must be match your SWF file.

Comment: If an answer is correct, please mark it as so. Otherwise Stackoverflow will never know that your problem has been solved. Consider to upvote answers that are somewhat helpful, doing so other users with similar question can find answers with more ease.